# AMP carousel inside lightbox not opening the taped/clicked image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, amp-html

I am working on the google AMP pages. I implemented the AMP-carousel inside an amp-lightbox so that if I have multiple images and I click on one, it opens up the lightbox with carousel behavior.

Everything works fine so far. but now that I have a design change so that I have one main image and three thumbnails images shown below the main image: in case I have four or more than four images.

So, for that, I would like to open whatever the image is clicked as the first image shown in the carousel.

I tried different workarounds but nothing helpful as of now. For Example, I tried the `on` property provided by AMP to pass the index value but I think it is for the lightbox directly not the carousel inside the lightbox.

**Here is the demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/kfd8e6sr/26/

you can see that, it is always opening the first image no matter whatever the image I am clicking.

**Code:**

```
<div class="img-container">
  <amp-img width="200" height="130" on="tap:my-lightbox" role="button" layout="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1">
  </amp-img>
</div>
<div class="img-container">
  <amp-img width="200" height="130" on="tap:my-lightbox" role="button" layout="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=2">
  </amp-img>
</div>
<div class="img-container">
  <amp-img width="200" height="130" on="tap:my-lightbox" role="button" layout="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=3">
  </amp-img>
</div>

<amp-lightbox id="my-lightbox" layout="nodisplay" on="tap:my-lightbox.close" tabindex="1">
    <amp-carousel dir="ltr" width="16" height="9" layout="responsive" type="slides"  on="tap:my-lightbox.close" role="button">
        <amp-img width="768" height="430" layout="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1">
        </amp-img>
        <amp-img width="768" height="430" layout="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=2">
        </amp-img>
        <amp-img width="768" height="430" layout="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=3">
        </amp-img>
    </amp-carousel>
</amp-lightbox>
```

Comment: Post code here.

Comment: @Shree updated the question

Comment: @Sami  check my answer, hope this help you?

Comment: thank you! that was really helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use on="tap:YOUR-CAROUSEL-ID.goToSlide(index=INDEX-NUMBER)"

Demo : [Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/kfd8e6sr/38/)

Code :

```
<div class="img-container">
  <amp-img width="200" height="130" on="tap:my-lightbox,carousel-with-preview.goToSlide(index=0)" role="button" layout="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1">
  </amp-img>
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <amp-img width="200" height="130" on="tap:my-lightbox,carousel-with-preview.goToSlide(index=1)" role="button" layout="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=2">
    </amp-img>
  </div>
<div class="img-container">
      <amp-img width="200" height="130" on="tap:my-lightbox,carousel-with-preview.goToSlide(index=2)" role="button" layout="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=3">
      </amp-img>
</div>

<amp-lightbox id="my-lightbox" layout="nodisplay" tabindex="1">
<button on="tap:my-lightbox.close">
Close
</button>
    <amp-carousel id="carousel-with-preview" dir="ltr" width="16" height="9" layout="responsive" type="slides"  role="button">
        <amp-img width="768" height="430" layout="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1">
        </amp-img>
        <amp-img width="768" height="430" layout="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=2">
        </amp-img>
        <amp-img width="768" height="430" layout="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=3">
        </amp-img>
    </amp-carousel>
</amp-lightbox>
```

Note : carousel index start from 0

**How to call Multiple actions for one event ?**

Example: on="tap:target1.actionA,target2.actionB"

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with this

```
<amp-carousel height='400' layout='fixed-height' type='slides' loop lightbox >
    <div class="article-gallery-item">
        <div class="article-gallery-img">
            <amp-img src="####"></amp-img>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
</amp-carousel>
```